# getting wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Hospital_Visit
      hid pid HospitalName DoctorId
      41   1  abc        1
      42   2  xyx        2

Patient_Master
       pid  PatientName
       1        jill
       2        rosy
Doctor_Master
      DoctorID DoctorName
       1        John
       2        Jack
Hospital_Study
      sid  hid  exam  status
       1    41   jjj   sfvn
       2    41   fks   jdjd

select  Hospital_Visit.Pid,PatientName,DoctorName from Patient_Master
inner join Hospital_Visit on Hospital_Visit.pid=Patient_Master.pid
inner join Doctor_Master on Doctor_Master.DoctorID= Hospital_Visit.DoctorID
inner join Hospital_Study on Hospital_Study.hid=Hospital_Visit.hid

Pid PatientName  DoctorName exam status
1   Jill         John       jjj  sfvn
2   rosy         John       fks   jdjd
```

**

```
//Correct output i want
    Pid PatientName  DoctorName exam status
    1   Jill         John       jjj  sfvn
    2   rosy         Jack       fks   jdjd
```

**

i am getting wrong result repeting doctor
 name in result because of `inner join` hid on Hospital_Visit and Hospital_Study 
How can i takle this problem

---

(DTU Edit - Current sample data in usable form):

```
create table Hospital_Visit(hid int,pid int,HospitalName char(3), DoctorId int)
insert into Hospital_Visit(hid, pid, HospitalName, DoctorId) values
      (41,   1,  'abc',        1),
      (42,   2,  'xyx',        2)

create table Patient_Master(pid int,  PatientName char(4))
insert into Patient_Master(pid,  PatientName) values
       (1,        'jill'),
       (2,        'rosy')
create table Doctor_Master(DoctorID int, DoctorName char(4))
insert into Doctor_Master(DoctorID, DoctorName) values
       (1,        'John'),
       (2,        'Jack')
create table Hospital_Study(sid int, hid int,  exam char(3),  status char(4))
insert into Hospital_Study(sid,  hid,  exam,  status) values
       (1,    41,   'jjj'   ,'sfvn'),
       (2,    41,   'fks'   ,'jdjd')
```

Comment: inner join Hospital_Study on Hospital_Study.hid=Hospital_Visit.hid because of this doctorname is repeting.

Comment: ya u r right john what is the solution for that i want data from Hospital_Study also

Comment: But in your output there is no column from hospital_study

Comment: @Nikhil You want to join on IDs rather than names. You can enforce the relationship between your tables MUCh more efficiently through that means. So, in Doc_Master, replace Doc name with DocID and join on that.

Comment: Can you show the output the way you want it?

Comment: You want data from `Hospital_Study` - but there are two matching rows there. So there are two rows in the result. If you want only one row, you need to give us/SQL the *rules* for how to combine multiple rows into a single one.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever  i didnt get ur point

Comment: Fluffeh i join on docid not on docname see my quetion  again

Comment: It's very difficult to diagnose the issue when your sample data doesn't match up. rosy doesn't appear in the result at all, since she only has an entry in `Patient_Master` and no other tables (and ignoring that your `SELECT` clause doesn't match your shown output). Please try to construct some sample data, current result, and expected result that actually work.

Comment: Now see i edit Hospital_Visit

Comment: Okay, so by what rule does the study with `sid` = 1 attach to Jill/John, and the study with `sid` = 2 attach to Rosy/Jack?

Answer (score 0):

With the sample data given right now ([revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11796081/4)), it's impossible to get the output you want.

Right now, your query returns this:

```
Pid PatientName DoctorName
1   jill        John
1   jill        John
```

What you want is this:

```
//Correct output i want
Pid PatientName  DoctorName exam status
1   Jill         John       jjj  sfvn
2   rosy         Jack       fks   jdjd
```

...but the data in the `Hospital_Study` table doesn't match this, because both lines have `hid = 41`:

```
Hospital_Study
  sid  hid  exam  status
   1    41   jjj   sfvn
   2    41   fks   jdjd
```

So they both reference the first row from the `Hospital_Visit` table, which belongs to the patient named "Jill".
--> with this data, it's impossible to select the patient named "rosy", because there is no row in the `Hospital_Study` table that refers to rosy's visit (`hid = 42`).

To get the desired output, the data in the `Hospital_Study` would need to look like this:

```
Hospital_Study
  sid  hid  exam  status
   1    41   jjj   sfvn
   2    42   fks   jdjd
        /\
        ||
        this is different
```

With this data, and the exact query from your question, you get this result:

```
Pid PatientName DoctorName
1   jill        John
2   rosy        Jack
```

Answer (score -2):

I have a doubt on your join

```
inner join Hospital_Study on Hospital_Study.hid=Hospital_Visit.hid
```

Hospital_Study.hid is Foreign key that's right but Hospital_Visit.hid is a primary key or is it a foreign key.

If Hospital_Visit.hid is a foreign key of then you have to add one more inner join on your Hospital's Master table (Hospital_Master).

Comment: Hospital_Visit.hid is primary key and Hospital_Study.hid is foreign key.

Comment: How  can add ne more inner join on Hospital's master